# C# Generics - out keyword - 'method has the wrong return type'

Tags: c#, generics, out

So, I have this program here:

```
public delegate R ReturnObject<out R>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ReturnObject<object> returnObject1 = ReturnObj;
    ReturnObject<string> returnString1 = ReturnString;
    ReturnObject<int> returnInt = ReturnInt;

    returnObject1 = ReturnString;


    Console.ReadLine();

}

static object ReturnObj() { return new object(); }
static string ReturnString() { return "hello"; }
static int ReturnInt() { return 1; }
```

This works. But when I do this:

```
returnObject1 = returnInt;
```

It gives me an error saying 'ReturnInt has the wrong return type' or something like that. But why? Int could be upcasted to object, right?

Thanks